# How would I create a dependant dropdown in a Html that is based on the output of one dropdown (i.e a department) and the total value of a jquery table

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm pretty new to scripting and am working on a project that needs me to pull over a list of people from googles dependant on which department we select in a html form and if the total in a jquery table is less than £250. I wondered if anyone had any examples that might help? I'm currently using javascript and html and a little jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might interest you
[Cascading select drop-down using jQuery and JSON data](https://www.encodedna.com/jquery/cascading-select-dropdown-list-using-json-data.htm)
The link above has an example with detailes explanation on the website...